# Creating a new data frame using only certain rows

Tags: r, rows

I have a data frame School_Behavior, I have a column called "school" which lists Mississippi or Jackson.  I want to create a new data frame with only the data from the rows of Mississippi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *filter* function from the dplyr package:

```
    library(dplyr)
    data <- School_Behavior %>% 
      filter(school =='Mississippi')
```

The pipe operator %>% is used to define your dataframe as input for the filter function.

Comment: Using that, I get a new data frame with all the data but each school response is "Mississippi"

Comment: It sounded like that was your requested output. How do you want your dataframe to look like?

Comment: I want a new dataframe, with only the rows including "Mississippi" as their 'school'. excluding the rows with "Jackson" listed as their 'school'.

Comment: That is exactly what the filter function should return:It keeps all rows with Mississippi as their school and removes all rows with Jackson as their school.

Comment: You can also drop the school column by adding **%>% select(-school)** after the filter, because every school is now mississippi

Comment: It instead changes all responses to 'Mississippi' in my original dataframe.

Comment: No it only keeps the rows with Mississipi as their school. You may be confuse because it keeps the school column which now only has the value Mississippi. But it should have dropped all other rows

Comment: you are correct!  I apologize for my confusion. Thank you!!